# LINQ Selecting Specific Data from 2 different XML Descendant

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm having a bit of problem here trying to pull data from an xml files that has 2 different descendants.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Male>
    <Person id="1" Name="Joe" Age="35" />
            ......  Some more data
    <Person id="6" Name="Hank" Age="55" />
</Male>

<Female>
    <Person id="4" Name="Jane" Age="28" />
    ......  Some more data
    <Person id="9" Name="Jude" Age="32" />
</Female>
```

So I want to extract the descendant Female only, so here's my code.

```
private int personId;
private string personName;
private int personAge

private async void GetPersonDetails()
{
    try
        {
         string personDetail = "http://localhost/people/directory.xml";
         HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
         HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, personDetail 

        // Send the request to the server
        HttpResponseMessage response2 = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        // Just as an example I'm turning the response into a string here
        string responseAsString = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument _xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(responseAsString);

var peopleData = from person in _xdoc.Descendants("Female")
    select new 
    {
         id = person.Attribute("id").Value,
         name = person.Attribute("Name").Value,
         age = person.Attribute("Age").Value      
     };

int peopleIdx = 0;
foreach (var pDetails in peopleData)
{
     personId = pDetails.id;
     personName = pDetails.name;
     personAge = pDetails.age;
     peopleIdx++; 
 }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

What happen is that it also extracted the male details as well.  How can I do it in order to get all the data from Female Descendent?  Basically the user could do a search either Male or female to get the results.

Comment: That is an invalid XML file. XML must have a single root; there are 2 roots in the sample.

Comment: As well as the problem Metro Smurf has pointed out, the code you've given wouldn't have extracted the values at all, as it's looking for *attributes* called `id`, `Name` and `Age` when you've actually got elements. Oh, and you're closing a `Person` element with a `person` end element. It's hard to help you when we don't know what the *real* data looks like (or potentially your real code).

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the source code that I used to actually pull data from my xml files.  If it only have 1 root, then I have no problems pulling the data.  So what you and Metro Smurf suggest that I should change the xml format?

Comment: @AhPek: What you've shown isn't a valid XML file at all. XML documents simply don't have multiple root elements. I'm surprised it isn't throwing an exception when parsing at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmmm.. Thanks for the input.  Then I guess I'll set the root as person, and add a the field Sex in order to determine if the person is Male or Female.  I thought it would be easier if I set the XML that way.  Thanks again for your input!  Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select elements named `Person` which are children of `Female`. You can use [`Enumerable.SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the children of `Female` elements and then process their data:

```
var people = _xdoc.Descendants("Female")
    .SelectMany(e => e.Descendants("Person"))
    .Select(e => new
    {
        Id = e.Attribute("id").Value,
        Name = e.Attribute("Name").Value,
        Age = e.Attribute("Age").Value
    });
```

Comment: You don't need `SelectMany` here - just `_xdoc.Descendants("Female").Descendants("Person)` is fine.